# R: wrapper function(fun, parameters) that calls fun with "unrolled" parameters

Tags: r

I would like to implement a generic function:

```
call_with_parameters <- function(func, parameters) {
    call func with parameters and return result
}
```

that calls the given function **func** (given as paramter) with a **list of parameters**, so func must not be able to cope with generic parameters (like ...). As return the call

For example to call: `mean(x=1:4, na.rm=TRUE)` as

```
call_with_parameters(mean, list(x=1:4, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you looking for `do.call`?

Comment: @agstudy - Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @agstudy I second Dason this should be answer...stop being lazy :-)

Comment: @Dason I post an answer. dickoa, I am never lazy to help :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you are looking for `do.call` for the construction of function calls.

The function constructs the call and  evaluates it immediately( *You can also use `call` to construct the call and evaluates it later using `eval` for example*). `do.call` takes the arguments
from an object of mode "list" containing all the arguments of function to be evaluated. For example:

```
do.call("mean", list(x=1:4,na.rm=TRUE))
```

is equivalent to :

```
mean(x=1:4,na.rm=TRUE)
```